# What is the difference between 'to be' and ' to become'?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I want to know the difference between 'to be' and 'to become'.

There are two sentences below

1. I want to be a president.
2. I want to become a president.

I think the two sentences are same.
If not, what is the difference in meaning?
What do you think of this?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23053/difference-between-be-and-become) of the question  [Difference between be and become](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23053/difference-between-be-and-become)

Comment: As Peter mentioned in his answer 'be' is just the state of sth\sb but 'become' describes a transition, a change. Expressing your wish in both ways is correct, but remember _to be_ a president, first you need _to become_ one.

Answer (score 3):

Usually using

> I want to become president.

implies there are *steps* or a *process* one must go through.

Saying

> I want **to be** president.

only emphasizes the *end point* or *goal*.

Either way the result, if successful, is that you are president.