# "Harry works hard to be/become a good student."

Tags: word-choice

> Harry works hard to be a good student.

> Harry works hard to become a good student.

Are both sentences acceptable? Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: Please see this. I think it can help you!https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23053/difference-between-be-and-become

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between be and become](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23053/difference-between-be-and-become)

Answer (score 1):

As for the meanings, they are not the same.

The first sentence implies that Harry is currently a good student, and the purpose of working hard is to maintain that standing. To that end, it may be more clear to write it as:

> Harry works hard to maintain his standing as a good student.

The second sentence implies that Harry is currently *not* a good student and the purpose of working hard is to reach that standing. Your example in that case is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you. This helps.